# Can't create facebook like button for a facebook page, says could not reach

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm trying to create like button on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ with the url of facebook page which is http://www.facebook.com/captainmorganlietuva but it doesnt work - says ERROR when i push LIKE. Any ideas?

Error says PAGE COULD NOT BE REACHED. Do I have to be admin of that page to create like button or something?

Comment: can you be more exact on what ERROR shows..?

Comment: The page at http://www.facebook.com/captainmorganlietuva could not be reached.

Comment: It does, at least in my country its visible.

Comment: Does the page have restrictions on it? Since it's alcohol, it may be set to be 21+, which could be inadvertently be interfering with the button. I would flag it as a bug if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure that this is the problem, or if I totally understand the problem but something jumped out at me - 
Why are you trying to create a like button for a Facebook Page that already has a like button on it? 
 If you are trying to connect that page's `like` button to a `like` button on a different URL then this is against facebook platform policy.  If you were able to do this people would be able to "trick" users into liking a URL they didn't mean to "like".

Comment: Many times brands want Like buttons that point to their Facebook presence. It gives them a single larger count than rather having one button for their Facebook page and another for their website, each with separate "like" counts. This is not against policy.

Comment: They may want to combine like counts - but you can not have "cross promotion" on facebook - the fact that the facebook page is connected to the website is purely coincidental.  Tomorrow that website changes, leaves the same URL and you have users inadvertently liking a website from a facebook page and a facebook page from a website.  A client of mine indeed DID have this request and indeed it was implemented and facebook did INDEED close both the URLS (of the site and of the page) and in addition my personal facebook account (because i was the sole administrator of that page)

Comment: in short - not recommended :)

Comment: I think we're talking about two different things. The simple act of giving users the option of liking a brand "on Facebook" via a Like button on an outside webpage (belonging to the brand) is fine. If the website changes or the url no longer reflects what the button is advertised as pointing to - then you have a problem.

Comment: still - you can't combine like counts.

Comment: All I need to do is to include a like button into a facebook page tab to like the same facebook page :) Of course I could just let users use the like button on the top of the page, but clients wants it in the tab itself as well :) and I keep getting that strange errror.